# Replacing whole lines with certain text in them in Notepad++

Tags: replace, notepad++, yaml

I am editing a large YAML file, and have this appear in the text many times (replaced actual text with placeholders):

```
options:
- placeholder1!
- this is a placeholder!
- %placeholderhere%!
- placeholder
- you get the point by now
- more placeholders
- one last placeholder...
this is just some text don't replace
options:
- placeholder1!
- this is a placeholder!
- %placeholderhere%!
- placeholder
- you get the point by now
- more placeholders
- one last placeholder...
```

I want to turn that into this:

```
options:
- placeholder1!
this is just some text don't replace
options:
- placeholder1!
```

Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: Don't know why I was downvoted... I made a typo

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but your question is a bit unclear. You want to reduce several lines to a single line?

Comment: Yes, but I want to replace multiple sets of lines like

replacethis
replacethis

just some text

replacethis
replacethis



change that all into 
replacethis

just some text

replacethis
@RaGe

Answer (score 0):

Input

```
options:
- placeholder1!
- this is a placeholder!
- %placeholderhere%!
- placeholder
- you get the point by now
- more placeholders
- one last placeholder...
this is just some text don't replace
options:
- placeholder1!
- this is a placeholder!
- %placeholderhere%!
- placeholder
- you get the point by now
- more placeholders
- one last placeholder...
```

Find `^options.*?- (placeholder1).*?placeholder...$`
Replace with `-\1!`

[image]

Note: don't forget to check `matches newline` checkbox (v6.0 onwards only)

Result:

```
-placeholder1!
this is just some text don't replace
-placeholder1!
```